# Alert message for the button click in iphone sdk 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, onclick, alert

I am beginner to xcode programming.Please tell me how to display the alert message when we are going to click the button in xcode-iphone-4.3

My Code is as follows,

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!!!!!!" 
                                                    message:@"This is the Iphone app" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [mes show];

    [mes release];
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)buttonOnePressed:(id)sender
 {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Clicked button 1"
                  message: @"Alert Message here"
                  delegate: self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

     [alert setTag:1];
     [alert show];
 }

-(IBAction)buttonTwoPressed:(id)sender
 {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Clicked button 2"
                  message: @"Alert Message here"
                  delegate: self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

     [alert setTag:2];
     [alert show];
 }
```

Below is the delegate method to track which button on Alertview is hit.

```
  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex   
   {
     if (alertView.tag == 1) { // UIAlertView with tag 1 detected
       if (buttonIndex == 0) 
       {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 0");
            // Any action can be performed here
       }
       else 
       {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 1");
            // Any action can be performed here
       }
     }

    else if (alertView.tag == 2) { // UIAlertView with tag 2 detected
       if (buttonIndex == 0) 
       {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 0");
            // Any action can be performed here
       }
       else 
       {
            NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 1");
            // Any action can be performed here
       }
     }
   }
```

You can set tag to `UIAlertView` in case you have more than one `UIAlertView`s and can determine which `UIAlertView` button is clicked in its delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex` using its respective tag.

Answer (score 1):

In IBAction you have to write the code and give the Connections to the Button

Comment: Thanks for responding.can u please tell me how to give the connections to the button

Comment: declare the - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;in .h file. And go to the .xib file.And there you will find the FilesOwner.Right click on it.Then you will find the method and drag that on to the Button and then it will shows popover.There you will find the TouchUpInside.Connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the IBAction for your button and add the code for alert view in that method.